# visual c++ RECT collision

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, collision-detection

I have just started with Win32 GUI programming, a few days ago. I am trying to make a simple game in which I need to detect collision between 2 objects.
So I made my *characters* using `RECT` struct

To detect if they collide I have used:

```
// Returns 1 if the point (x, y) lies within the rectangle, 0 otherwise
int is_point_in_rectangle(RECT r, int x, int y) {
    if ((r.left   <= x && r.right >= x) &&
        (r.bottom <= y && r.top   >= y))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

// Returns 1 if the rectangles overlap, 0 otherwise
int do_rectangles_intersect(RECT a, RECT b) {
    if ( is_point_in_rectangle(a, b.left , b.top   ) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(a, b.right, b.top   ) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(a, b.left , b.bottom) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(a, b.right, b.bottom))
        return 1;
    if ( is_point_in_rectangle(b, a.left , a.top   ) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(b, a.right, a.top   ) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(b, a.left , a.bottom) ||
         is_point_in_rectangle(b, a.right, a.bottom))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Which I found on a question here, and it seems to work for situations like [this](http://puu.sh/2loUa). But there is a small problem with it this situation [here](http://puu.sh/2loVS)

Is there any way to fix that? Am I doing it wrong? Should I try a different approach?
Any tip will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly checking if corners of one rectangle are inside the other is a bad idea:

[image: Intersecting rectangles]

A simple way to do the check is instead:

```
if (a.left >= b.right || a.right <= b.left ||
    a.top >= b.bottom || a.bottom <= b.top) {

   // No intersection

} else {

   // Intersection

}
```

Comment: Thank you i end up adding this at the end of the function i originally used and it seems to do the job

Comment: This code does the whole check and it can **replace** that function entirely. Try to spend some time with paper and pencil to understand why it is sufficient for all possible cases.

Comment: In that picture none of the 4 conditions seems to be met, and therefore an intersection is reported (as it should). I'm assuming of course that left<right and top<bottom (as it's normal for win32 coordinate system where (0,0) is top-left).

Comment: Can you give names to those values? For example if they're `(left, top)-(right, bottom)` this would mean `top > bottom` for both first and second pair.

Comment: yes L,T R,B it returns no intersection and they are obviously intersecting

(-1,0),(1,-2)

(0,1), (2, -1)

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference now but for what is worth you were right i made an error back then. This condition is sufficient for the collision and nothing else is required. 

Thank you for your help back then.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at API functions:

- [PtInRect function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [IntersectRect function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - "If the rectangles intersect, the return value is nonzero."

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not valid. You may have two rectangles intersect without having any of teh vertices of any of them lying in the other one. For instance `((0,0), (10,10))` and `((5,-5), (7, 15))`. Try checking if a **side** of one of the rectangles intersects the other rectangle.